# Trying to add new form fields for additional data and getting weird return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery script that is supposed to create new table and input fields with a _1 for the new data field. The code does add the table and the fields however the input fields have this when doing a view source of the code.

I am not sure why I am getting [object Object]1 for the form fields.

Also if I add an additional table the other fields get this.

visitor_first_name_NaN where this should be 2 or 3

I am sure I am missing something just not sure what.  If anyone has an idea or a fix it would be great.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("##visitorRegFrm").validate({
        errorElement : "div",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent("td") );
        }
    });
});

var arr = new Array();
    arr[#qrStaff.currentrow#] = new Array();
    arr[#qrStaff.currentrow#][1] = '#qrStaff.Staff_Last_Name#';
    arr[#qrStaff.currentrow#][2] = '#qrStaff.Staff_Email#';
    arr[#qrStaff.currentrow#][3] = '#qrStaff.Staff_First_Name#';
function changeEmp(obj){
    //console.log(jQuery(obj).val());
    jQuery('##employee_last_name').val(arr[jQuery(obj).val()][1]);
    jQuery('##employee_email').val(arr[jQuery(obj).val()][2]);
    jQuery('##employee_first_name_text').val(arr[jQuery(obj).val()][3]);
}
jQuery.format = function(source, params) {
    if ( arguments.length == 1 ) 
        return function() {
            var args = jQuery.makeArray(arguments);
            args.unshift(source);
            return jQuery.validator.format.apply( this, args );
        };
    if ( arguments.length > 2 && params.constructor != Array  ) {
        params = jQuery.makeArray(arguments).slice(1);
    }
    if ( params.constructor != Array ) {
        params = [ params ];
    }
    jQuery.each(params, function(i, n) {
        source = source.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "g"), n);
    });
    return source;
};


jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
incdecVar = 1;
jQuery(function() {
        var scntDiv = jQuery('##addTable');
        var i = jQuery('##addTable table').size + 1;

        jQuery('##addNewVistor').on('click', function() {
                jQuery('<table class="newTbl" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5"><tr><td colspan="4"><h3>Visitor Information</h3><a href="##" class="btn_link" id="remNewVisitor">Remove</a></td></tr><tr><td width="25%">First Name:<span class="verror"></span></td><td width="25%"><input type="text" name="visitor_first_name_' + i +'" value="" class="required"/></td><td width="20%">Last Name:<span class="verror"></span></td><td width="30%"><input type="text" name="visitor_last_name_' + i +'" value="" class="required"/></td></tr><tr><td>Title:<span class="verror"></span> </td><td><input type="text" name="visitor_title_' + i +'" value="" class="required"/></td><td>Company:<span class="verror"></span> </td><td><input type="text" name="visitor_company_' + i +'" value="" class="required"/></td></tr><tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="visitor_phone_' + i +'" value=""/></td><td>Email:<span class="verror"></span> </td><td><input type="text" name="visitor_email_' + i +'" value="" class="email"/></td></tr></table>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                jQuery('input##Counter').replaceWith('<input type="hidden" name="Counter" id="Counter" value="'+ i +'" />');
                newValue = parseInt(jQuery('input##Counter').val())+1;
                jQuery('input##Counter').val(newValue);
                incdecVar += newValue;
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        jQuery('##remNewVisitor').on('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        jQuery(this).parents('.newTbl').remove();
newValue = parseInt(jQuery('input##Counter').val())-1;
                jQuery('input##Counter').val(newValue);
                incdecVar -= newValue;
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});

});//]]>  
</script>
```

Comment: what is $().size? Seems like deprecated method. Object object probably means that given object has not toString method. Mostly its accidentaly caused by using whole object instead of just property..

Comment: Yes, what is `$(...).size`? Only `.size()` and `.length` have been valid for checking jQuery collection lengths and `.size()` was deprecated in 1.8. If `.size` is `undefined` then `.size + 1` gives `NaN`.

Comment: I did read that .size() had been depreciated, I also did remove the .size and have nothing.  I still get name="visitor_first_name_[object Object]1 and 
name="visitor_first_name_NaN" when adding any more like 3rd and 4th one.

var i = jQuery('##addTable table') + 1;

I also tried 
var i = jQuery('##addTable table').size + 1;

with the same results. 

So how do I define .size + 1?